# Serilog is made as a logging plugin and no log files are generated in the project directory after deploying and running the windows service

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

My project is c#6.0, after deploying it as a windows service, after the project runs, the log file is not generated in the directory, but in the C:\Windows\System32 folder

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Settings.Configuration",
      "Serilog.Expressions"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {      
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService": "Error",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Error",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Error",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "【时间】{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}{NewLine}【等级】{Level}{NewLine}【消息】[{SourceContext}]{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@l = 'Debug'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "logs/Debug/.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileTimeLimit": "7.00:00:00", 
                  "outputTemplate": "【时间】{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}{NewLine}【等级】[{Level}]{NewLine}【消息】[{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@l = 'Information'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "logs/Information/.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileTimeLimit": "7.00:00:00",
                  "outputTemplate": "【时间】{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}{NewLine}【等级】[{Level}]{NewLine}【消息】[{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@l = 'Warning'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "logs/Warning/.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileTimeLimit": "7.00:00:00",
                  "outputTemplate": "【时间】{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}{NewLine}【等级】[{Level}]{NewLine}【消息】[{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@l = 'Error'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "logs/Error/.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileTimeLimit": "7.00:00:00",
                  "outputTemplate": "【时间】{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}{NewLine}【等级】[{Level}]{NewLine}【消息】[{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I guess it is because the project is running in windows service, so the running path is under the system32 folder path, so the log relative path configured is c:\windows\system32, I want to generate the log file in the directory where the program is running